# How do I read DB data and output all data with an alert only once in php?

Tags: javascript, php

After reading the data from the DB, you can use foreach to output all the data. But I want to print out the printed data as an alert at once, what should I do?

this is my code

```
foreach($result as $row){     
            print_r("excel_number:".$row['excel_index']." / "."fail_reason:".$row['reson_result']."<br>");  
    } 

$total_fail_log = "excel_number:".$row['excel_index']." / "."fail_reason:".$row['reson_result']."<br>";
        echo "<script>alert('$total_fail_log');</script>";
```

and print result

[image]

and alert result

[image]

When output as alert, only the last value is output. How do I print out the whole thing like the first picture?

Comment: In your loop, add/concatenate your message to a string, alert the string (which now contains all messages) after your loop

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate all your data to a string. Then pass the sctring to an alert function.

```
<?php

$alert_string = "";

// add each line to the $alert_string (added \n for formatting)
foreach($result as $row) {
    $alert_string .= "excel_number:".$row['excel_index']." / "."fail_reason:".$row['reson_result']."<br>\n";
}

// print the result as an alert script
echo "<script>alert(`$alert_string`);</script>";
```

Feel free to tweak the code according to your need.

Answer (score -2):

You can put the alert inside the foreach loop and it will be executed from inside. By doing this, according to the output, you should have two alerts.

Comment: How do I print out one alert?